# Why does Keycloak admin-cli client receive 403 Forbidden for listing groups?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

We're using keycloak-admin-client-12.0.4.jar to obtain groups via `GroupsResource.groups`, and receive an `HTTP 403 Forbidden` when doing so on one of our environments (it does work on another). 403 seems to mean that the secret we use for the admin-cli client is OK, but somehow, the admin-cli client is not allowed to list groups (I also tried with a wrong secret and got 401 in that case).
Now we're trying to verify that the admin-cli client is correctly configured on that environment to allow this.

To our surprise, it's not at all obvious how this is configured, or whether it's configurable at all. The admin-cli client that is pre-configured in a vanilla Keycloak Docker image doesn't have any roles assigned, so how does Keycloak know what it is allowed to do? Is `admin-cli` maybe hardcoded into Keycloak with certain rights? And if so, why would we be receiving a 403 then?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that in the "Clients / admin-cli" view, in the tab "Service Account Roles", one has to select something in the drop down "Client Roles" in order to see what is configured, while intuition would say that this would change the configuration instead of only reading it. In the dropdown, we had to select "realm-management", revealing a lot of "Available Roles", out of which we had to add "manage-users" to the "Assigned Roles."

[image]

Comment: There is no Service Account Roles